# Is it safe to backup volumes of running mariadb docker containers

Tags: backup, docker, database

Is it safe to backup data volumes of a running mariadb / postgres / mysql container?
Should I stop the container prior to backing up the volumes?

Answer (score 0):

Not without additional steps.

The on-disk files will likely be internally inconsistent, so a snapshot of them would have to go through a recovery process, which (ideally) would roll back any uncommitted transactions and get you back to a consistent state. That will, however, only work on atomically taken snapshots, as that situation is basically equivalent to a power loss in the middle of a transaction.

The [Backup and Restore Overview](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/backup-and-restore-overview/) page suggests either pulling a logical backup with `mysqldump`, or freezing all tables temporarily (`FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK`) and taking a snapshot. Note that this stalls all modifying transactions until the client disconnects or `UNLOCK TABLES` is executed, so ideally the snapshot mechanism should be fast (like a LVM or ZFS snapshot).

Comment: Thank you. I am using Duplicati right now to backup my docker volumes. Then I will create a cronjob which dumps the relevant database to sql and backup the sql file instead.